# Choropleth Africa map doesn’t show some countries and islands

Tags: plotly, plotly-python, choropleth

I’m plotting an African continent map using choropleth. However, some regions are not appearing on the map, even the respective alpha codes being correct. For example, I have data from Seychelles (sov_a3="SYC"), Mauritius (sov_a3="MUS"), and the map is missing these regions or is not filled.

There is something I’m missing? I didn’t see a complete Africa map made with Plotly and I’m wondering if there is some issue with the parameter scope=“africa”

Follow below the code for the map and how it looks now.

```
fig_map = go.Figure(px.choropleth(df_map,
                            locations='sov_a3', color=map_count_column,
                            hover_name='country', animation_frame="date_2weeks",
                            color_continuous_scale="algae",
                            range_color=[0, max(df_map['cum_counts'])],
                            labels={'cum_counts': 'Number of genomes'}
                            ))
    fig_map.update_layout(geo_scope="africa")
```

[image: Choropleth map of African continent]

Comment: I think you need to prepare your own geojson as shown in this [sample graph](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/#choropleth-map-using-geojson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- it's all down to geometry / geojson.  See documentation https://plotly.com/python/map-configuration/#physical-base-maps. Natural earth is used,  which does not define these islands as part of Africa
- have simulated a data frame for your code.  To create MWE

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

countries = 'TZA,ESH,COD,SOM,KEN,SDN,TCD,ZAF,LSO,ZWE,BWA,NAM,SEN,MLI,MRT,BEN,NER,NGA,CMR,TGO,GHA,CIV,GIN,GNB,LBR,SLE,BFA,CAF,COG,GAB,GNQ,ZMB,MWI,MOZ,SWZ,AGO,BDI,MDG,GMB,TUN,DZA,ERI,MAR,EGY,LBY,ETH,DJI,UGA,RWA,SSD'
names = "Tanzania,W. Sahara,Dem. Rep. Congo,Somalia,Kenya,Sudan,Chad,South Africa,Lesotho,Zimbabwe,Botswana,Namibia,Senegal,Mali,Mauritania,Benin,Niger,Nigeria,Cameroon,Togo,Ghana,Côte d'Ivoire,Guinea,Guinea-Bissau,Liberia,Sierra Leone,Burkina Faso,Central African Rep.,Congo,Gabon,Eq. Guinea,Zambia,Malawi,Mozambique,eSwatini,Angola,Burundi,Madagascar,Gambia,Tunisia,Algeria,Eritrea,Morocco,Egypt,Libya,Ethiopia,Djibouti,Uganda,Rwanda,S. Sudan"
# Seychelles (sov_a3="SYC"), Mauritius (sov_a3="MUS")
countries += ",SYC,MUS"
names += ",Seychelles,Mauritius"
map_count_column = "cum_counts"

# simulate implied dataframe in question
df_map = (
    pd.DataFrame({"sov_a3": countries.split(","),"country":names.split(",")})
    .merge(pd.DataFrame({"date_2weeks": list("ABC")}), how="cross")
    .assign(
        cum_counts=lambda d: np.random.randint(1, 5, len(d)),
    )
)

# go.Figure is spurious remove
fig_map = px.choropleth(
    df_map,
    locations="sov_a3",
    color=map_count_column,
    hover_name="country",
    animation_frame="date_2weeks",
    color_continuous_scale="algae",
    range_color=[0, max(df_map["cum_counts"])],
    labels={"cum_counts": "Number of genomes"},
)
fig_map.update_layout(geo_scope="africa")
```

- now I use a different geojson where the islands are defined.  However this is imperfect as I have not ensured names map correctly to geojson
- this does show Mauritius

```
import requests
res = requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codeforgermany/click_that_hood/main/public/data/africa.geojson")

# use out own geometry
fig_map = px.choropleth(
    df_map,
    geojson=res.json(),
    locations="country",
    featureidkey="properties.name",
    color=map_count_column,
    hover_name="country",
    animation_frame="date_2weeks",
    color_continuous_scale="algae",
    range_color=[0, max(df_map["cum_counts"])],
    labels={"cum_counts": "Number of genomes"},
)

fig_map.update_geos(fitbounds="locations")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Rob! It was the best solution to the problem.